# Выбор одного значения из каждой группы в таблице БД при помощи LINQ и Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Есть таблица в БД с примерно такой структурой:

```sql
table
(
    id int,
    field1 varchar,
    field2 datetime
)
```

Задача - выбрать для каждого уникального значения field1 самую новую запись (по полю field2). В чистом SQL обычно делаю так:

```sql
select *
from
(
    select  *,
            row_number() over(partition by t.field1 order by t.field2 desc)
    from table as t
) as q
where q.rn = 1
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать что-то подобное на LINQ? Я пробовал выбирать так:

```csh
var topList = list.GroupBy(l => l.field1, (key, g) => g.OrderByDescending(l => l.field2).First()).ToList();
```

Работает, но только на локальных списках, в MS SQL не транслируется (выдаёт ошибку трансляции).

Точно работает

```csh
var topList = list
              .Where(l => l.Id == 
                list.Where(l2 => l2.field1 == j.field1)
                    .OrderByDescending(j2 => j2.field2)
                    .First().Id)
              .ToList();
```

Но оно транслируется в

```sql
select *
from table as t
where id = (select top 1 id
            from table as t2
            where t2.field1 = t1.field1
            order by field2)
```

что, по-моему, некрасиво и неоптимально.

Используется .Net Framework 4.6.1, Entity Framework Core 3, MS SQL 2014.

**Update**

Решение из https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980568/row-number-over-partition-by-xxx-in-linq не подходит, так как, видимо, не поддерживается EF и не транслируется в SQL.

Comment: Вы можете найти решение по этой ссылке: [Row_number over (Partition by xxx) in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980568)

Comment: Уточните, какую именно версию EF используете. От этого зависят варианты ответа.

Comment: Использую Entity Framework Core 3.

Comment: `.Net Framework` как бы уже устарел. Уж скоро .NET 6 выйдет.

Comment: @aepot, в данном случае это большой роли не играет, проблема в ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оконные функции не поддерживаются ни `LINQ`, ни транслятором EF. Тем не менее, вы не первый, кто озадачился таким вопросом и эта фича уже есть в [бэклоге](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12747).

---

Относительно же вашей ситуации можно посоветовать 2 варианта:

1. Используйте то, что уже есть, если оно выполняет вашу задачу. То, во что оно транслируется, вовсе необязательно может быть плохо. Посмотрите ближе, сравните планы. Если всё не так плохо, то оставьте. Если же вариант с окнами выполняется **значительно** эффективнее или ненамного эффективнее, но этот запрос является **узким местом**, то используйте:
2. [Нативный запрос](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, придётся использовать то, что есть. На тех объёмах данных, что обрабатываются, существенной разницы нет.

Comment: Поправлю: оконные функции не поддерживаются Entity Framework'ом (как обычным, так и Core). Но LINQ тут не при чём.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вы правы, речь конечно о провайдере. реализация зависит ведь не только от EF, но и от поддержки провайдера. когда EF реализует эту фичу ей нельзя будет пользоваться, пока провайдер не добавит поддержку этой возможности

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал вместо EF Core использовать гораздо более мощную и гибкую ORM LINQ to DB. В частности, в ней [реализована](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/Window-Functions-%28Analytic-Functions%29.html) полная поддержка оконных функций.

Если страшно вот так сразу отказаться от EF (ведь это разработка самой Microsoft!), то советую попробовать библиотеку [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore). Она позволит использовать все возможности linq2db в EF Core.

Эта библиотека находится в списке [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/). Там можно и другие полезные расширения найти. А "голый" EF весьма уныл.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! К сожалению, выбор ORM не в моей власти, приходится использовать то, что есть. LinqToDb возьму на заметку.

Comment: @АлександрСуханов - Но библиотеки-то можно использовать?

Comment: Предложу на следующем обсуждении.

Comment: интересная штука, но как жить без трекера? идентити кажется тоже поддерживается так себе

Comment: @Anatol - Если вас действительно интересует, как обходиться без трекера и идентити, то задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Прямо сейчас не настолько сильно интересует